# Teaching Bread Making to a young student- need new reasources

Tags: baking, bread

Hi Seasoned Advice Forum Members
I am a semi experienced Artisan Bread Baker. I am currently teaching a 9 year old boy the basics of bread making and would like to see if anyone has any  suggestions on where I can find free educational material on Bread making that is not too heady, that would benefit my student

Comment: Hello Tarus and welcome! I'm hoping that you or I (or another user) can edit your question. Recipe requests are off topic for the site, but I think an appropriate edit can maybe get you some answers.

Comment: Sorry. Tried to edit but can't find a way out of the recipe request that maintains the idea of the question. But i have to say, if you're a semi-experienced Artisan Bread Maker, where did you learn from? That may well be your answer.

Comment: my step Father worked as a professional baker for years... He has passed along some of his knowledge and i am proficient in the execution of bread making in his style... however passing along these methods may not be the best for the student i am working with as he is 9 years old... and the ratio method of bread making seems to not work for him... just looking for good simple recipes... King Arthur Flour has some good simple ones but wanting to expand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Josey Baker Bread book. He is a former elementary school science teacher turned professional San Francisco baker. The lessons start with the simplest no-knead bread and progressively add to that foundation with new concepts and techniques.  In a number of ways it feels like an elementary school science textbook.  It might be the best match for what you are looking for.

http://www.joseybakerbread.com/the-book

Answer (score -1):

I am a huge fan of the modernist cuisine series including modernist bread, I have them all except the photography one. There are curious omissions, for example they have a photograph and description of every type of mixer including the uncommon Ankarsrum/Electrolux and diving arms but they somehow missed fork mixers. Nevertheless, it is astonishingly complete. They have performed ridiculous amounts of testing across everything bread related that they knew about including water of varying hardness, varying ph and every combination of home equipment they could think of. The recipes have a lot of information about adapting them to different baking situations.

If like me, you were sick of not being able to search your paper copy, I might point out there is a chrome extension that can search certain libraries that American politicians are not fond of and perhaps some other options.

Having said that I am not a huge bread baker and there are doubtless other excellent resources.